# How to redirect to another view on the same project with href attribute in Knockout

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC project with Knockout.
On my View (for example: 'aa' under the 'aa' folder: aa/aa) I have an a tag that redirect the user to another view ('bb' under the 'bb' folder: bb/bb) as the below:

```
<a href="~/bb/bb">
```

Now I have to change my href to include a parameter in the query string so I changed it to use the Knockout href attribute:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: 'bb/bb?number=' + number()}">
```

The issue is that my link looks like this:

```
".../aa/bb/bb?number=test"
```

Any advice?

Comment: The code you posted (i.e. the second html snippet) [will *not* produce the link you claim](https://jsfiddle.net/uaoq2j2c/) AFAICT. Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Razor view engine is only capable of transforming `href="~/ctrl/action"` to its equivalent `Url.Action("action", "controller")` call. But, when your path is encapsulated within a Knockout-specific directive, it won't detect it.

Try this instead:

```
<a href="~/bb/bb" data-bind="attr: { href: $element.href + '?number=' + number() }"></a>
```

This way, Razor still transforms your `href` to the correct path and later Knockout relies on the element's original value to construct the final url.

See [Binding-Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)

---

**Update:**

Actually, there's a subtle bug in the above approach that involves re-concatenating the `href` value once the observable changes and the expression is being re-evaluated.

Here's a revised version:

```
<a url="~/bb/bb"
   data-bind="attr: { href: $element.getAttribute('url') + '?number=' + number() }"></a>
```

Comment: Working! Excellent answer! Thank you for the explanation, it helped me to understand it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: I understand, I tried it but again this is the link I get: ".../aa/~/bb/bb?number=test", Any idea?

Comment: @user3378165, Apparently, Razor wouldn't detect `data-href` as well. I changed it to `url` instead. Alternatively, you can go with `data-href="@Url.Action("...", "...")"` instead.